# Is it legal to enter a country you're a citizen of without using passport check points?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Say I'm just gonna walk back home. Is that legal?

I'm a regular "joe" with no bad stuff on my background anywhere in the world. I have valid id, passport and all that

Comment: Depends on the country. Specify which country are you referring to.

Comment: Whether legal or not, in most places it would give the impression that you are someone they need to investigate.  And in some places that could be very unpleasant.

Comment: IANAL, but it does not appear to be illegal in Canada (aside from potentially trespassing or whatever to actually get there), however there are provisions to detain the person, with prescribed internal periodic reviews after 48h, 7d, and every 30d after that. Grounds include inability to identify the person, flight risk, and potential for risk to the public.  OTOH, a boater who crosses the border and does not immediately report to the authorities is subject to a minimum $1,000 fine and can have their boat impounded. Eg. a guy was recently fined the $1k for having breakfast before reporting.

Comment: Depends on  the border, not country.
The forementioned Russia has different borders: some can be crossed freely, some cannot.

Comment: This is an answerable question *if* you say which border of which country you are talking about. We don't have 'too broad' as a specific close reason, but to ask a question simultaneously about _every jurisdiction in the world_ surely is exactly that - too broad.

Comment: This is obviously a speculative question, which means only speculative answers are possible. In general, arbitrary crossing of a border is only possible if there's an international treaty in force, enabling specifically that. Otherwise no. Even though in most countries (not all!) citizens have inalienable right to enter their country of citizenship, immigration controls are still required to check whether or not someone indeed is that country's citizen or not.

Comment: @jno AFAIK, no Russian border can be crossed freely. Even the Russian border with Belarus is not "free" in the Schengen sense. There are border checkpoints to prevent 3rd party nationals from entering Russia. Belarusian and Russian nationals enjoy freedom of movement, but they, too, must present their IDs and their travels are recorded.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko yes, you're *mostly* right. But there is no penalty for crossing some borders not via checkpoints. It's not what most travelers want, but in occasional use of local people.

Comment: @jno Can you please give an example of a border where 1.) there are checkpoints 2.) there's no penalty for bypassing them? I'm really interested.

Answer (score 18):

Contrary to Mark's answer, I would rather assume the opposite and that it in most countries even for the citizens of that country, is illegal to enter the country outside designated border control posts.

Within the Schengen area, borders can of course be crossed everywhere, but crossing an external Schengen border outside designated border control posts (both entering and leaving) is also for EU/EEA citizens prohibited. Even if EU/EEA citizens in most cases can't be refused access to any country in the Schengen area, they are still subject to an immigration check at the border. Crossing the Norwegian-Russian border illegaly is for example usually sanctioned with a roundabout 1000€ fine.

I know there are a few local exceptions in very remote areas, but entering the US is just as well [only allowed through staffed ports of entry](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-782?language=en_US). As CBP points out in the linked article, although it is usually not a violation of US law to leave the US at an arbitrary point, you will at the land borders immediately violate Mexican or Canadian law by doing so since you are only allowed to enter Mexico or Canada through designated ports of entry.

Comment: The border between Belgium and The Netherlands in Baarle-Hertog runs *though*  houses and even before Schengen  it was certainly not illegal to cross the border and go from your kitchen to your living room directly and back again without going trough a border control point...

Comment: @diya But was it *generally* allowed to cross the border at any point, or were there just local exceptions for the very particular situation in Baarle-Hertog? Also at the US/Canadian border, there are local exceptions for houses situated directly at the border. I am not 100% sure now, but isn't the situation in Baarle-Hertog regulated in such a way, that a house or an apartment is considered to be entirely in the country, in which the main entrance door is located, even if the border technically runs through the apartment?

Comment: Before Schengen, Belgium and The Netherlands (and Luxemburg) had (and still have) the Benelux which also eliminated border controls between those three countries. I don't know how things were regulated in Baarle-Hertog / Baarle-Nassau before that.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, Yes, I believe the location of the main entrance door defines which country your house or business is in, which matters for all kinds of regulations that differ between countries, such as tax rules. Moving your front door a few meters can mean effectively moving from one country to another IIRC.

Comment: The Baarle case is not that simple. See this video from Arte.tv: [Baarle a town of two nations](https://www.arte.tv/en/videos/101463-002-A/crazy-borders/).

Comment: "_bother_ entering and leaving" or "_both_ entering and leaving"? (Not enough rep to make that small an edit.)

Comment: see also Stanstead, Quebec/Derby Line, Vermont.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derby_Line%E2%80%93Stanstead_Border_Crossing

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you. I fixed the typo now.

Comment: Also, in some countries/regions, there are restricted border zones which one may not enter without permission. So that in itself might be an offense.

Comment: I would _so_ install French doors if I lived there ...

Comment: I remember a canoe trip in the 1980's starting in the U.S. Boundary waters and crossing into Canada's Quetico.  The Canadians had a crossing station right at the border, while the U.S. station was a 20 mile drive after you got back to a road.  I don't know if things have changed since then.

Comment: The mention of Quebec by @Yorik reminded me: The [Mohawk Nation at Akwesasne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akwesasne) consists of 3 of contiguous Native American reservations that span New York, Ontario, and Quebec. There is long-running dispute, particularly with Canada, where the Mohawk residents maintain that under their sovereignty they have right to freely cross the border, which includes the movement of goods, specifically cigarettes.

Comment: @MarkRansom Also see the Alcan highway when it crosses into Alaska, the US facility is on the border, but the Canadian crossing is 18 miles into Canada. Until 1971, the US facility was 90 miles in, so it would be over 100 miles between them. There's also border crossing on the Klondike Highway to Skagway, it's 8 miles into the US which Wikipedia claims is the furthest US crossing from the actual border.

Comment: There are a lot of unmanned border crossing points between Switzerland and neighbouring countries. And they were there before Switzerland joined Schengen. Similar situations existed in many other places. People certainly crossed borders at places other than official border crossings, even then.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Sure, but based on special agreements between the two neighbouring countries and not *in general*. Switzerland is in the special situation that it is only surrounded by 'friendly' countries. If we look at e.g. Germany instead, the situation before Schengen was that more or less free border crossings toward Switzerland was possible, while crossing into Poland or the Czech Republic was only allowed at checkpoints. The legal default in Germany is still that border crossings are only allowed at designated points, but there more exceptions to the rule than use of the rule itself.

Comment: Yes, and what was also usually part of the special agreement was that only citizens of the countries involved could use these informal crossings. But that would apply in the case the OP brought up here.

Comment: For every country with notoriously difficult to get visa and prohibition against entering like the OP asks, on foot, there is a border post somewhere where at least the locals can do just that, and without ID. Example: some crossings from China to Vietnam, Burma and even Hong Kong.

Comment: @Kostas Definitely not in every country. If we ignore the borders to the micro states, which are de facto considered as part of the Schengen area (e.g. San Marino and the Vatican State), there is no 'hole' in the external Schengen border where locals or anyone else can cross without immigration checks.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, nice examples. I had in mind this: on a yacht sailing website about going by private boat from Greece to Turkey and back: "... it has become possible – and popular – to cross the border by simply changing the courtesy flag half-way while avoiding the bigger ports (i.e. start and finish in a small port or bay). This illegal practice is now widely condoned: all the customs appearently will do is send the yacht back when caught." And as I was saying, even LESS obstacles for locals.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases <strike>yes</strike> no, since Immigration laws apply mostly only to non citizens, they must check if they apply to each person crossing a border (citizen or non citizen).

Then there are cases when a citizen is not actualy allowed to leave their country in the first place due to certain criminal records.

Since many borders are also a **customs** border, which applies to everyone, crossing at certain points can also be required for customs checks.

Comment: At least in my country, India, its illegal to avoid the immigration.

Comment: For US, its not a crime, I think.

Comment: @AnishSheela: it is not avoiding immigration, and i really doubt that it is the absolute truth in India, considering the strange border between India and Pakistan. And the question is not about general entry, but own citizen and without bans.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I think by "immigration," Anish means "immigration control," which is exactly what the question is about (crossing the border at a non-designated point would necessarily involve avoiding immigration control, i.e. passport checks.)

Comment: Another instance - Singapore - Malaysia border. Its only less than one km to swim in ocean. But its very illegal even if you are a Singapore citizen. You will be in jail for six months.

Comment: @AnishSheela Singapore is well known for being unreasonably strict in all legal matters.  I'm not sure they make a good example for what's normal.